# Naïve approach to constructing a chaos sudoku

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, sudoku

I was recently reminded of the *jigsaw sudoku*, which is a sudoku variant where each of the nine regions that need to be filled with the numbers from 1 to 9 are irregular regions instead of square regions. This made me wonder about how these puzzles are constructed, and whether there will always be a way to construct a jigsaw sudoku given a filled 9-by-9 grid where each of the numbers 1 to 9 appear exactly once on each row and each column in the grid.

More generally, let $M_n$ be a Latin square of size $n$ (i.e. $M_n$ contains every natural number from $1$ up to $n$ as an entry in each row and each column).

A collection of $k$ connected (by travelling horizontally and/or vertically, but not diagonally) entries in $M_n$ is called a ***$k$-region***. If $R$ is an $n$-region formed from a single row or column in $M_n$, $R$ is called ***trivial***. If $n$ is a perfect square and $R$ is an $n$-region formed from a square submatrix of $M_n$, $R$ is called ***regular***. If an $n$-region $R$ is neither trival or regular, $R$ is called ***irregular***.

Suppose $\Sigma_n$ is a collection of $n$ non-overlapping $n$-regions $R_i$ formed from $M_n$, such that each $R_i\in \Sigma_n$ is formed from entries with values ranging from $1$ up to $n$. Then the pair $(M_n,\Sigma_n)$ is called an ***$n$-sudoku template***. If each $R_i\in\Sigma_n$ is trivial, then $(M_n,\Sigma_n)$ is said to be ***trivial***; if $n$ is a perfect square
and each $R_i\in\Sigma_n$ is regular, then $(M_n,\Sigma_n)$ is said to be ***regular***. Otherwise, if each $R_i\in\Sigma_n$ is irregular, then $(M_n,\Sigma_n)$ is said to be ***chaotic***.

It quickly becomes apparent that there cannot be a chaotic $n$-sudoku template with $n\leq 3$ but I have a hard time figuring out what happens for larger values of $n$.

Also immediately apparent is that no matter what, if $M_n$ is a Latin square there is always a $\Sigma_n$ such that $(M_n,\Sigma_n)$ is a trivial $n$-sudoku template.

> Q1. Suppose that $n\geq 3$ and that $M_n$ is a Latin square of size $n$. Is it always possible to find a $\Sigma_n$ such that the $n$-sudoku template $(M_n,\Sigma_n)$ is not trivial? If not, is there any number $n$ enabling us to find such a $\Sigma_n$ no matter how $M_n$ looks?

If the answer to the above question is positive, then the following question may be relevant:

> Q2. Suppose that $n\geq 4$ and that $M_n$ is a Latin square of size $n$. Is it always possible to find a $\Sigma_n$ such that the $n$-sudoku template $(M_n,\Sigma_n)$ is chaotic? If not, is there any number $n$ enabling us to find such a $\Sigma_n$ no matter how $M_n$ looks?

I have no idea how to answer the above questions, but I suspect that maybe graph/Ramsey theory could be required at some point.

Comment: The puzzlers'  name for "chaos" Suduku" is "jigsaw Sudoku", assuming that the regions are polyominoes.  And there is cylindric jigsaw Suduku in which opposite edges of the 9x9 (or $n^2$x$n^2$) grid are identified.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ah, I see. I had no idea about this; "chaos sudoku" is just a literal translation from my native language to English. Maybe I should edit that too then?

Comment: I suppose the modern way of composing a Sudoku or a variant of it for a puzzle site is to throw a few numbers onto  a grid and use a software solver to determine that  a solution exists, and keep adding more numbers until the software reports that there is a unique solution.  Not mathematically interesting, as the software will likely use massive trial-and-error.

Comment: I don't think you need to edit out "chaos". Your definition is clear. I thought it might help if you are looking for references

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yeah. I think changing from "chaos sudoku" to "jigsaw sudoku" is generally a good idea, but other than that there isn't much of a point in changing the terminology.